# How can I call the external module in mean stack application

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here i have created an external module "lang-change" in which i created one service and one directive.

**bower_components/lang-change/lang-change.js**

```
angular.module('langChange', [
   'angular-translate'
])
.service('MyService', function ($translate, $rootScope, tmhDynamicLocale) { 
    .............
    .............
    .............
})
.directive('LanguageChangeSelect', function (MyService) { 
    'use strict';
  return {
    .............
    .............
    .............
  };
});
```

I created this module seperately and link this to bower_components, but when I am using this in my app.js, I am getting error.

**error**

```
angular.js:12783 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: langChangeProvider <- langChange
```

**app.js**

```
(function() {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('myApp', [
    'ngSanitize',
    'ui.router',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'pascalprecht.translate',// angular-translate
    'tmh.dynamicLocale'// angular-dynamic-locale
  ])
  .config([
    '$stateProvider',
    '$urlRouterProvider',
    '$injector',
    '$translateProvider',
    'tmhDynamicLocaleProvider',
    function(
      $stateProvider,
      $urlRouterProvider,
      $injector,
      $translateProvider,
      tmhDynamicLocaleProvider
    ) {
        $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
          url: '/',
          templateUrl: 'views/home.html'
        })
        .state('myapp', {
        url: '/myapp',
        templateUrl: 'views/myapp.html',
        controller: ['$scope', '$state', '$rootScope', '$translate', 'langChange',
        function($scope, $state, $rootScope, $translate, langChange) {
          // Code goes here
        }]
      });
   }
]);
```

Comment: `langChange` is angular `module` not `provider`, you can only inject `provider/service/factory/constant/value` as dependencies..what you wanted to achieve, do explain it.

Comment: change `'langChange'` in your controller dependencies to '`MyService`' - 'controller: ['$scope', '$state', '$rootScope', '$translate','MyService' ' -- for reasons in the comment above